# can java script be used as a scripting language in qtp and how?

Tags: qtp

Like vbscript, we use property and value methods for writing the script. How to write java script for qtp?

Comment: Have you tried checking http://www.google.com for any hints?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 1):

QTP tests are written in VBScript, there is no support for other languages.
You can run some browser-side JavaScript using the `Browser.RunScript` method (starting in QTP11) but the test itself is VBS only.